# How to directly redirect user to home page if user is already logged in in nativescript-vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to redirect a user to the home page if they are already logged in, otherwise redirect to login page.

How can I solve this in nativescript-vue?

Comment: Depends on your implementation, backend solution, your storage approach etc. So, give as much required detail and code snippets as possible.

Comment: When first time user install and open app , then login into app we store user info in localstorage. Then again user when open the app, based on localstorage data app should redirect to home page

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are passing Login component to the render function in `app.js`. You could write a condition statement there, pass Home component if user is logged in already.

If you have to hit server for validating the token, either you could use a loading page Or navigate to home with clear history option once the validation is done.

Comment: Sorry that's a good question, I haven't been using NativeScript-Vue recently. They used to support it partially earlier, but with latest version it's marked as unsupported.

Comment: Any alternate solution

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: if(localStorage.getItem('token') != null && localStorage.getItem('shop_id') != null){
    new Vue({
  render: h => h('frame', [h(Home)])
 }).$start();
  }
  else{
 new Vue({
  render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
 }).$start();
  }                                                                                                                                                         Correct???

Comment: Yes, I think that should do.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check database( like sqlite or loki) for login status, in my case i check db from app.js then if status is 1 go to home page else go to login page, am not using {N}vue but plain(vanilla Js) but its the same, Heres code from App.js

````
if (  model.isAvailable ==true) {
    var whichPage=true;
    console.log(" User found");
}else{
    whichPage=false;
        console.log("Going to Acount page !");
}

var pageToload= whichPage ? "home":"status";
application.start({ moduleName: pageToload })
;```
Change it to how you like to handle it, model.isAvaillable() is a function that checks the Db for login status
````

Answer (score 0):

Vue Router appears to be unsupported right now according to the documentation (https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/vue-router/).

You can probably achieve what you're trying to do with something like this:

`const token = localStorage.getItem('token')`

`const shopId = localStorage.getItem('shop_id')`

`let userLoggedIn = false`

`if (token && shopId) {
  userLoggedIn = true
}`

`new Vue({
  render: h => h('Frame', [h(userLoggedIn ? Home : App)])
}).$start()`

I tried to use the logic you provided on 2/20.